# WS-Security actions explanation specifically SAML related

Tags: web-services, saml-2.0, wsse

The [WSHandlerConstants](http://people.apache.org/~coheigea/stage/wss4j/1.6.4/site/apidocs/org/apache/ws/security/handler/WSHandlerConstants.html) class defines action constants like SAML_TOKEN_SIGNED and SAML_TOKEN_UNSIGNED

I am struggling to find any documentation about these action constants, after looking around a lot I am still unable to find explanation for the below

- Mapping of action constants to the expected behaviour they are
  suppose to trigger
- Which constant should be defined on the outgoing end (client) versus
  which constants should be defined on the incoming end (server), if a
  constant can be used at both ends then how does its behaviour change.
- What effect does each constant have on the SAML token being produced

I am investigating actions related to SAML authentication and generation.

After digging through the source I have found that in the [WSSConfig](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.ws/com.springsource.org.apache.ws.security/1.5.8/org/apache/ws/security/WSSConfig.java) there is default action mapping.However the action classes only get invoked via the WSS4JOutInterceptor.

The WSS4JInInterceptor uses the actions configured on the server side to work out if the tokens are valid,I however could not work out exactly how.

I suspect that there should be some easy way to find out these different combinations. At the end I hope to have some clarity on,

If a SAML token is generated with these(X,Y,Z) characteristics then it can be validated successfully when CXF is configured with these (A,B,C) actions and a brief explanation for each of them. Some guidance on best practices and most used combinations wouldn't hurt.